# Needs some ideas on how to notifiy domain users either ASP.NET or SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to alert some domain users when a SQL database insert happens via ASP.NET MVC. We do not want email or txt. We prefer a alert of some sorts. I was thinking msg.exe via web or using xp_cmdshell  but not sure what the best way would be or if these are even options. Does anyone have any ideas or thoughts on the best way to do this?

Thanks,
EB

Comment: Uh, if you don't want an email alert, what kind of "alert" are you looking for? You want to develop a full application to install on your users system that will simply notify them of an error in SQL? And that doesn't seem like a ridiculous amount of work to reinvent the wheel to you?

Comment: Well I would prefer to use msg.exe but I can not seem to figure out how to launch that from either a web post or a sql statement.

Comment: What about a UDP multicast?  Or make use of IRC?